# Flutter, multiple packages, multiple lib folders

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am now studying flutter architecture.

But the example I am looking at is a strange structure. There is one lib folder at the project level and two custom folders at the project level, and there is also a lib folder, a pubspec, and even a dart file in it.

Also, the dart file of the original lib folder refers to the dart file with strange folders outside it (for example, custom Repository dart file).

[image]

Is this structure common? Why do you do this?

Isn't it possible to implement the same function by creating a new folder in the original lib folder?

Comment: i dont think this is normal

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it possible to implement the same function by creating a new folder in the original lib folder?

Yes, it is. Provided that you leave out some stuff (e.g. the pubspec.yaml file).

But what I think the author is doing, is that (s)he is is bundling up everything that is necessary for a specific feature, and is using it as a package: as in those packages that you get from pub.dev. A reason for doing this, is **so that you can much more easily use that feature in another app**.

For example, imagine developing a 'authentication feature'. You might use that feature in app 'A', but in 6 months time you may also want to use that same feature in app 'B'. Instead of having to find all the code related to your authentication feature and bundling it up, you can just copy/link to the feature you've already created.

Comment: Is it a good practice to have multiple libs in a project?